# How to close two forms simultaneously on the load of third form?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

There are three forms in my project, first is welcome form, second is server form and third is home page.

When a specific button is clicked on welcome form, server form is loaded without closing the welcome form. Now on the click of any specific button on server form, home page should be loaded and both welcome for and server form should be closed or hidden.

When I tried `this.Close(); Home_Page hp=new Home_Page(); hp.Show();` method on the click of the button of server form, only server form got hidden but Welcome form still runs in the background.

What should be done to close both Welcome form and server form on the load of Home_Page?

Comment: WinForms?  WPF?  Silverlight?

Comment: Question s all about WinForms

Answer (score 0):

use events and delegates to get the job done. What you can do is, make the Welcome form subscribe for an exit event from server form. Now in server form intern subscribes to home page. So upon clicking some button in home page, raise exit event there, which calls Server forms exit events and then raise event on welcome form, so close the welcome form and then close server form.
May not be the best solution, but i am open for suggestions.
I have no idea if this will work for silverlight/wpf if your problem is related to it.

Comment: Thank you zenwaklker for the support. I would like to use your solution in my project. But on my research I found one more solution which can be use to solve the given question. Solution is posted below.

Comment: Sure, i would love to hear that better solution, please edit your post itself for the same. Also, please vote if you like my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Solution of above given question is found.

On the click of button on server form, `this.Hide();` should be used to hide server form and then `Welcome.ActiveForm.Hide();` can be used to hide the welcome form. Then create an object of `Home_Page` and show that form using `Home_Page hp=new Home_Page(); hp.Show();`. `ActiveForm` makes the Welcome form the current active form and then it can be hidden.